# About iOS distribution certificate expire

Tags: ios

My app is already in Apple Store. Now my distribution certificate is expired. I know my app in Apple Store will continue running, but **my questions are:**

1. If now I have a bug fix in my app, does it mean I am not able to submit the updated app to Apple Store since my distribution certificate expired?
2. If I renew the distribution certificate, my understanding is that it is identical as revoke the distribution certificate and create a new distribution certificate, am I right?
3. If the answer to my 2nd question is "Yes", does it mean in future when I see my distribution certificate is expiring soon, I just revoke it and create a new one for existing app in Apple Store, am I right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am fine to close it. I will move to apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload your app to iTunesConnect, Apple resigns your binary with their own certificate. This means that your distribution certificate is *not* used in the App Store. That said...

1. You can submit a bug fix, just recreate your certificate in the developer portal
2. I am unsure about this. Renew could simply be revoke+create in a single step.
3. You can do that, but it really doesn't matter. You only need your distribution cert to submit to the App Store. This means your distribution cert could be expired for a long time during development of bug fixes and you can just recreate one to submit to the App Store.